# Freeswitch - Parse Call Detail Record information

Tags: php, freeswitch

I have Freeswitch server sending CDR information (A leg only) in JSON to PHP script and I need to parse extension and phone number in every scenario possible:

- Incoming call from PSTN to: user, group, callcenter app (answered, un-answered)
- Outgoing call to PSTN from user (answered, un-answered)

Each scenario have to use different variable in the JSON - depends if was bridged or not, if it's incoming (destination_number), if it's outgoing (caller_id_number), etc.

I was using **bridge_uuid** to detect if the call was bridged, but still got calls where bridge_uuid is missing and last_app is bridge (with status ORIGINATOR_CANCEL).

I put together 7 scenarios, but still there are calls, where phone number appear in extension for some reason and vice-versa.

Is there any simple way to get this information from CDR?

**SCENARIO 1:**

- outbound
- bridge_uuid = exists
- extension = callflow.0.caller_profile.caller_id_number
- number = callflow.0.caller_profile.destination_number

**SCENARIO 2:**

- outbound
- bridge_uuid = not exists
- extension = callflow.0.caller_profile.destination_number
- number = callflow.0.caller_profile.caller_id_number

**SCENARIO 3:**

- outbound
- bridge_uuid = not exists
- last_app = bridge
- extension = callflow.0.caller_profile.caller_id_number
- number = callflow.0.caller_profile.destination_number

---

**SCENARIO 4:**

- inbound
- bridge_uuid = exists
- cc_agent_bridged = exists
- extension = callflow.0.caller_profile.originatee.originatee_caller_profiles.0.destination_number
- number = callflow.0.caller_profile.caller_id_number

**SCENARIO 5:**

- inbound
- bridge_uuid = exists
- cc_agent_bridged = not exists
- extension = callflow.0.caller_profile.caller_id_number
- number = callflow.0.caller_profile.destination_number

**SCENARIO 6:**

- inbound
- bridge_uuid = not exists
- extension = NULL
- number = callflow.0.caller_profile.caller_id_number

**SCENARIO 7:**

- inbound
- bridge_uuid = exists
- cc_agent_bridged = not exists
- extension = ???
- number = ???

### **JSON CDR**

```
  'core-uuid' => 'bf6eef3c-16b7-4f61-8cc2-1cd73460268e',
  'switchname' => 'freeswitch',
  'channel_data' =>
  array (
    'state' => 'CS_REPORTING',
    'direction' => 'outbound',
    'state_number' => '11',
    'flags' => '0=1;2=1;22=1;40=1;42=1;45=1;116=1;117=1',
    'caps' => '1=1;2=1;3=1;4=1;5=1;6=1;8=1;9=1;10=1',
  ),
  'callStats' =>
  array (
  ),
  'variables' =>
  array (
    'direction' => 'outbound',
    'is_outbound' => 'true',
    'uuid' => 'c9aa9f5f-7afd-46af-8cca-2af25b758aec',
    'call_uuid' => 'c9aa9f5f-7afd-46af-8cca-2af25b758aec',
    'session_id' => '4755',
    'sip_profile_name' => 'homeoffice',
    'video_media_flow' => 'disabled',
    'text_media_flow' => 'disabled',
    'channel_name' => 'sofia/homeoffice/4012%40XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A56955',
    'sip_destination_url' => 'sip%3A4012%40XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A56955%3Btransport%3DUDP%3Brinstance%3D845ce1bf3f9efbf1%3Bfs_nat%3Dyes%3Bfs_path%3Dsip%3A4012%40XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A56955%3Btransport%3DUDP%3Brinstance%3D845ce1bf3f9efbf1',
    'origination_caller_id_name' => 'Name%20Surname',
    'origination_caller_id_number' => '1829XXXXXXX',
    'EXT_ID' => '163748',
    'USER_ID' => '793',
    'ID_TYPE' => 'application',
    'callgroup' => 'local',
    'dialed_user' => '4012',
    'dialed_domain' => 'pbx.domain.com',
    'sip_invite_domain' => 'pbx.domain.com',
    'presence_id' => '4012%40pbx.domain.com',
    'originate_early_media' => 'true',
    'rtp_use_codec_string' => 'OPUS,G729,PCMU,PCMA,GSM',
    'local_media_ip' => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    'local_media_port' => '17432',
    'advertised_media_ip' => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    'audio_media_flow' => 'sendrecv',
    'rtp_local_sdp_str' => 'v%3D0%0D%0Ao%3DFreeSWITCH%201646156158%201646156159%20IN%20IP4%20XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%0D%0As%3DFreeSWITCH%0D%0Ac%3DIN%20IP4%20XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%0D%0At%3D0%200%0D%0Am%3Daudio%2017432%20RTP/AVP%20102%2018%200%208%203%20103%20101%0D%0Aa%3Drtpmap%3A102%20opus/48000/2%0D%0Aa%3Dfmtp%3A102%20useinbandf
ec%3D1%3B%20maxaveragebitrate%3D30000%3B%20maxplaybackrate%3D48000%3B%20ptime%3D20%3B%20minptime%3D10%3B%20maxptime%3D40%0D%0Aa%3Drtpmap%3A18%20G729/8000%0D%0Aa%3Dfmtp%3A18%20annexb%3Dno%0D%0Aa%3Drtpmap%3A0%20PCMU/8000%0D%0Aa%3Drtpmap%3A8%20PCMA/8000%0D%0Aa%3Drtpmap%3A3%20GSM/8000%0D%0Aa%3Drtpmap%3A103%20telephone-e
vent/48000%0D%0Aa%3Dfmtp%3A103%200-15%0D%0Aa%3Drtpmap%3A101%20telephone-event/8000%0D%0Aa%3Dfmtp%3A101%200-15%0D%0Aa%3Dptime%3A20%0D%0Aa%3Dsendrecv%0D%0A',
    'sip_outgoing_contact_uri' => '%3Csip%3Amod_sofia%40XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A5090%3E',
    'sip_req_uri' => '4012%40XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A56955%3Btransport%3DUDP%3Brinstance%3D845ce1bf3f9efbf1',
    'sip_nat_detected' => 'true',
    'sofia_profile_name' => 'office',
    'recovery_profile_name' => 'office',
    'sofia_profile_url' => 'sip%3Amod_sofia%40XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A5090',
    'sip_local_network_addr' => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    'sip_reply_host' => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    'sip_reply_port' => '56955',
    'sip_network_ip' => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    'sip_network_port' => '56955',
    'sip_user_agent' => 'Z%205.5.9%20v2.10.17.3',
    'sip_allow' => 'INVITE,%20ACK,%20CANCEL,%20BYE,%20NOTIFY,%20REFER,%20MESSAGE,%20OPTIONS,%20INFO,%20SUBSCRIBE',
    'sip_recover_contact' => '%3Csip%3A4012%40XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A56955%3Btransport%3DUDP%3E',
    'sip_full_via' => 'SIP/2.0/UDP%20XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A5090%3Brport%3D5090%3Bbranch%3Dz9hG4bKS6tvm613tKgpg',
    'sip_recover_via' => 'SIP/2.0/UDP%20XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A5090%3Brport%3D5090%3Bbranch%3Dz9hG4bKS6tvm613tKgpg',
    'sip_from_display' => 'Name%20Surname',
    'sip_full_from' => '%22Name%20Surname%22%20%3Csip%3A1829XXXXXXX%40pbx.domain.com%3E%3Btag%3DDc8U2HQFrDQ4D',
    'sip_full_to' => '%3Csip%3A4012%40XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A56955%3Btransport%3DUDP%3Brinstance%3D845ce1bf3f9efbf1%3E%3Btag%3De4ab0722',
    'sip_from_user' => '1829XXXXXXX',
    'sip_from_uri' => '1829XXXXXXX%40pbx.domain.com',
    'sip_from_host' => 'pbx.domain.com',
    'sip_to_params' => 'transport%3DUDP%3Brinstance%3D845ce1bf3f9efbf1',
    'sip_to_user' => '4012',
    'sip_to_port' => '56955',
    'sip_to_uri' => '4012%40XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A56955',
    'sip_to_host' => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    'sip_contact_params' => 'transport%3DUDP',
    'sip_contact_user' => '4012',
    'sip_contact_port' => '56955',
    'sip_contact_uri' => '4012%40XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A56955',
    'sip_contact_host' => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    'sip_to_tag' => 'e4ab0722',
    'sip_from_tag' => 'Dc8U2HQFrDQ4D',
    'sip_cseq' => '48533003',
    'sip_call_id' => '7ba03d12-1451-123b-ff84-ac1f6b94e36c',
    'hangup_cause' => 'NO_ANSWER',
    'hangup_cause_q850' => '19',
    'digits_dialed' => 'none',
    'start_stamp' => '2022-03-01%2018%3A26%3A30',
    'profile_start_stamp' => '2022-03-01%2018%3A26%3A30',
    'progress_stamp' => '2022-03-01%2018%3A26%3A30',
    'end_stamp' => '2022-03-01%2018%3A27%3A30',
    'start_epoch' => '1646173590',
    'start_uepoch' => '1646173590060292',
    'profile_start_epoch' => '1646173590',
    'profile_start_uepoch' => '1646173590060292',
    'answer_epoch' => '0',
    'answer_uepoch' => '0',
    'bridge_epoch' => '0',
    'bridge_uepoch' => '0',
    'last_hold_epoch' => '0',
    'last_hold_uepoch' => '0',
    'hold_accum_seconds' => '0',
    'hold_accum_usec' => '0',
    'hold_accum_ms' => '0',
    'resurrect_epoch' => '0',
    'resurrect_uepoch' => '0',
    'progress_epoch' => '1646173590',
    'progress_uepoch' => '1646173590620111',
    'progress_media_epoch' => '0',
    'progress_media_uepoch' => '0',
    'end_epoch' => '1646173650',
    'end_uepoch' => '1646173650000174',
    'caller_id' => '%22Name%20Surname%22%20%3C1829XXXXXXX%3E',
    'duration' => '60',
    'billsec' => '0',
    'progresssec' => '0',
    'answersec' => '0',
    'waitsec' => '0',
    'progress_mediasec' => '0',
    'flow_billsec' => '0',
    'mduration' => '59940',
    'billmsec' => '0',
    'progressmsec' => '560',
    'answermsec' => '0',
    'waitmsec' => '0',
    'progress_mediamsec' => '0',
    'flow_billmsec' => '0',
    'uduration' => '59939882',
    'billusec' => '0',
    'progressusec' => '559819',
    'answerusec' => '0',
    'waitusec' => '0',
    'progress_mediausec' => '0',
    'flow_billusec' => '0',
    'sip_hangup_disposition' => 'send_cancel',
    'sip_invite_failure_status' => '487',
    'sip_invite_failure_phrase' => 'CANCEL',
  ),
  'callflow' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'profile_index' => '1',
      'caller_profile' =>
      array (
        'username' => '',
        'dialplan' => '',
        'caller_id_name' => 'Name Surname',
        'ani' => '1829XXXXXXX',
        'aniii' => '',
        'caller_id_number' => '1829XXXXXXX',
        'network_addr' => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
        'rdnis' => '',
        'destination_number' => '4012',
        'uuid' => 'c9aa9f5f-7afd-46af-8cca-2af25b758aec',
        'source' => 'src/switch_ivr_originate.c',
        'context' => 'default',
        'chan_name' => 'sofia/office/4012@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:56955',
      ),
      'times' =>
      array (
        'created_time' => '1646173590060292',
        'profile_created_time' => '1646173590060292',
        'progress_time' => '1646173590620111',
        'progress_media_time' => '0',
        'answered_time' => '0',
        'bridged_time' => '0',
        'last_hold_time' => '0',
        'hold_accum_time' => '0',
        'hangup_time' => '1646173650000174',
        'resurrect_time' => '0',
        'transfer_time' => '0',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
$data = json_decode($data_above, true);
$bridged = isset($data['variables']['bridge_uuid']);
$callcenter = isset($data['variables']['cc_agent_bridged']);
$direction = $data['variables']['direction'];
$extension = $data['callflow'][0]['caller_profile'];

$extension = match($direction)
{
    'inbound'=>match($bridged)
    {
        true => match($callcenter)
        {
            true => $extension['originatee']['originatee_caller_profiles'][0]['destination_number'],
            false => 'caller_id_number'
        },
        false => ''
    },
    'outbound'=>match($bridged)
    {
        true => 'caller_id_number',
        false => $data['variables']['last_app'] == 'bridge' ? 'caller_id_number' : 'destination_number'
    }
};
```

Comment: For your info, CDR means [Call Detail Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_detail_record), and not the primitive operation within LISP.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Don't get your comment, sorry?

Comment: So where is the [mcve]?  Where is the sample input data?  I see a lot of scenarios, but no actual PHP code.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry, updated.

Comment: Why use `match()` blocks when a simple ternary expression will do?  Maybe you are trying to avoid nested ternaries.  But then you should probably avoid nexted `match()`s for the same reason.

Comment: You used the tag "CDR" in your question, which is a [primitive operation within LISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR). I removed it, and explained why I did that. Apart from that: You're also limiting your question to a very select audience if you require them to know what CDR stands for.

Comment: @mickmackusa Readability I guess and I wasn't sure if is simple true/false solution in every case.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Got it, I didn't know about LISP operation. But I think who knows what is Freeswitch, would understand the relation, anyway will change it, thank you!